# Can the cosine function be written in "simpler" expressions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I recently found that the constants $\pi$ and $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $ can be related by the identity 
$$
2\cos \frac{\pi}{5} = \phi.
$$

Is there some way to write the cosine function by "simpler" mathematical expressions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's an example of an expression you would want to write that "naively" involves $\cos$ and might be simplified to not explicitly involve $\cos$ using this identity?

Comment: The expression is incorrect, and is also not an equation. It should be $\phi = 2\cos(\pi/5)$. (Also, I don't see the need to put those equations on a separate line, @Chinny84.)

Comment: Yes, sorry. You are correct that the equation was supposed to be 2cos(π/5). Fixing.

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals#List_of_trigonometric_constants_to_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000074-QINU.60.22.27.7F

Comment: So it just so happens to be a constant, but cannot be expressed as a general rule in an equation?

Comment: I guess my question boils down to, if I don't have a calculator how would I establish what an angle is from a given set of side lengths? Before computers were around there must have been some other equation used to express what we now call Cosine, right?

Comment: Before computers were around, the same equations were used that are used now.

Comment: @mkinson Let's say I don't have a computer and I want to find the angle opposite the side of length 8 in a triangle with side lengths 4,7,8. Then I'd write $8^2=4^2+7^2-2\cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cos(\theta)$, then $\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{56}$, so $\theta=\arccos(1/56)$. I'd then have to approximate this arccos using any of a number of approximation techniques, most of which are based in calculus and not trigonometry alone. One way would be to write it as $\pi/2-\int_0^{1/56} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$ and then approximate the integral.

Comment: @mkinson However, I think in reality this problem (common in, say, nautical  navigation) would've been solved by looking up cosine values in a table, where the cosine values would've been computed using Taylor series (possibly supplemented by other tricks).

Comment: The question has been put on hold. Can someone please help me with how is this question unclear? How can I improve the question?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on transcendental functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function) may be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More generally, $$\cos(nx) = {\large{T_n}} (\cos(x))$$ where $T_n$ is the $n$'th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.

So, for example, since $T_5(t) = 16 t^5 - 20 t^3 + 5 t$, and $\cos(\pi) = -1$, we find that $t = \cos(\pi/5)$ satisfies
$$ 16 t^5 - 20 t^3 + 5 t + 1 = 0 $$
That polynomial can be factored as $(t+1)(4 t^2 - 2 t - 1)^2$, and since $t \ne -1$ we conclude that $t$ is a root of $4 t^2 - 2 t - 1$, thus $(1 \pm \sqrt{5})/4$.

This method can be used to express the cosine of any rational multiple of $\pi$ as the root of some polynomial with rational coefficients.  However, in most cases there is not such a nice expression of this root.

Answer (score 7):

Well, we know Euler's formula:

$$e^{\theta i}=\cos\left(\theta\right)+\sin\left(\theta\right)i\tag1$$

So, we also get:

$$e^{\theta i}+e^{-\theta i}=2\cos\left(\theta\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\cos\left(\theta\right)=\frac{e^{\theta i}+e^{-\theta i}}{2}\tag2$$

Now, we have:

$$2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\phi=2\cdot\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{5}}+e^{-\frac{i\pi}{5}}}{2}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{5}}+e^{-\frac{i\pi}{5}}\tag3$$

Comment: I believe step two gives me what I was looking for, where e is roughly 2.718281828459... and i is an imaginary number?

Comment: For $e$ we have $e:=\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\text{n}}\right)^\text{n}=2.71828182845904523536\dots\tag1$ and $$i^2=-1\tag2$$

Comment: Why was this voted down? Does it not accurately represent Cosine?

Answer (score 6):

Gauss introduced a method for cyclotomic polynomials that quickly gives such expressions. Let $n$ be odd and $\omega$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Then one of th values indicated by the expression $\omega + (1/\omega)$ is, indeed, $ x =2 \cos (2 \pi / n).$ These satisfy monic polynomials with integer coefficients. If you prefer $ x =2 \cos ( \pi / n)$ you need half angle formulas.

Oh, given the way these are constructed, all the roots are real and given by $2 \cos 2k\pi/n$

Fairly consistent for prime $n.$

$n=5$
$$ x^2 + x - 1 $$

$n=7$
$$ x^3 + x^2 -2x-1 $$

$n=11$
$$ x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3x +1 $$

$n=13$
$$  x^6 + x^5 - 5 x^4 - 4 x^3 + 6 x^2 + 3 x - 1 $$

$n=17$
$$ x^8 + x^7 - 7 x^6 - 6 x^5 + 15 x^4 + 10 x^3 - 10 x^2 - 4 x + 1  $$

$n=19$
$$ x^9 + x^8 -8 x^7 - 7 x^6 +21 x^5 + 15 x^4 -20 x^3 - 10 x^2 +5 x + 1  $$

These are all in pages 3-23 of [Reuschle (1875)](https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false). I learned the method in *Galois Theory* by David A. Cox, and wrote working programs for fixed polynomial degrees 3, 5, 7.

[image]

Comment: What with the soccer screenshot?

Comment: @Asaf Enthusiasm. Wonderful match.